# accessing data from fetch response

Tags: javascript, fetch

When I run this code I get below response

```
getText(priceUrl, options)
async function getText() {
    let x = await fetch(priceUrl, options);
    let y =  x.text()

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
    //document.getElementById("tokenPriceUsd").innerHTML = usdPrice;
    console.log(y['nativePrice']['value'])
    document.getElementById("tokenPriceBnb").innerHTML = y['usdPrice'];


}
```

y is this response

```
{"nativePrice":{"value":"0","decimals":18,"name":"Binance Coin","symbol":"BNB"},"usdPrice":0,"exchangeAddress":"0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73","exchangeName":"PancakeSwap v2"}
```

now when I try to access those values to use them in my frontend

```
 //document.getElementById("tokenPriceUsd").innerHTML = usdPrice;
    console.log(y['nativePrice']['value'])
    document.getElementById("tokenPriceBnb").innerHTML = y['usdPrice'];
```

I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: y.nativePrice is undefined
```

I can not access the values and if I use x.json() I only get back promis object

I know there are quiet a few questions about fetch, but I still cant figure out on how to access the values from my response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read up on Response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json)

You may find this helpful as well...

> The Response object, in turn, does not directly contain the actual JSON response body but is instead a representation of the entire HTTP response. So, to extract the JSON body content from the Response object, we use the json() method, which returns a second promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

You can await until the promise is resolved. Like `y = await x.json()`

Comment: its not working, y is undefined plus I get 
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: Did you try the second method?